# Access Age Range Query Not Returning Ages Less Than 1

Tags: ms-access

I have a query in my Access database that takes 2 user inputted ages and returns database entries that are between those inputs. It works fine when you input a range where the lowest value is >=1 but if the lowest value is < 1 then it won't return anything, even though entries exist where this is true.

Initially I thought this might be something to do with how I'm calculating the ages (I'm doing this on the fly within the query) so I tried with and without the datediff functions:
(Date()-[DOB])/365.25
and
Age: (DateDiff("y",[DOB],Date()))/365.25
but neither of those made any difference to the results. Is it related to the age calculation or is there something in the between...and operator that isn't working?

The complete SQL code for this part of the query is:

```
DateDiff("y",[DOB],Date()))/365.25) Between [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Youngest Age in Range] And [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Oldest Age In Range]
```

And the code for the whole query is (inclusive of edits suggested by Gustav):

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Youngest Age in Range] Short, [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Oldest Age in Range] Short, [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup] Short, [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch] Short;
SELECT [Carer Contact Details_1].[Parents Name], [Carer Contact Details_1].[Parents Surname], [Carer Contact Details_1].[Email Address], [Carer Contact Details_1].[Contact Number], [Carer Contact Details_1].Postcode, [Child Details1].[First Name], UCase(Left(Nz([Child Details1].[Gender],""),1)) AS Gender, Round((DateDiff("d",[DOB],Date())/365.25),2) AS Age, [Child Details1].DOB, [Child Details1].[Date of Last Test]
FROM [Carer Contact Details_1] INNER JOIN [Child Details1] ON [Carer Contact Details_1].[Parent ID] = [Child Details1].[Parent ID]
WHERE (((UCase(Left(Nz([Child Details1].[Gender],""),1))) Like Choose([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup],"M","F","[MF]")) AND ((Round((DateDiff("d",[DOB],Date())/365.25),2)) Between [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Youngest Age in Range] And [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Oldest Age In Range]) AND ((Left([Carer Contact Details_1]![Postcode],Len(Nz([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch]))))=Nz([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![PostcodeSearch])));
```

Obviously, my expected result is that it is able to handle values less than 1 i.e. can search for and find values from 0.1 - 0.9. Currently, it returns blank.

I'm quite new to both Access and SQL, so I apologise if this has an obvious solution that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I thought I would update this as I'm still having problems with this. I have tried both of the suggestions listed below (by Gustav and SunKnight0) but neither has worked. It still won't return anything less than 1 year old (and interestingly, if I set the Age part of the query to return the age in days then it won't return anything less then 525 days). I thought this might be due to missing values in the "Gender" field of my search form, as it wasn't returning any entries that did not have an entry in that field (regardless of age). With that in mind I added this line:

```
((UCase(Left(Nz([Child Details1].[Gender],""),1)))
```

To the part of the query where I select the designated gender. I've updated the whole query above so it reflects the most recent attempt I'm working on.

I'm completely stumped now as to why it won't return anything less than. Is it something to do with the functions I use to calculate age? Does DateDiff do some automatic rounding down or something?

Answer (score 0):

It is "yyyy", not "y" (the day of the year) - but use a function that calculates age correctly like this:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

Then your query will be:

```
Parameters 
    [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Youngest Age in Range] Short,
    [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Oldest Age In Range] Short;
Select
    *,
    AgeSimple([DOB])
From
    YourTable
Where
    AgeSimple([DOB]) Between [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Youngest Age in Range] And [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![Oldest Age In Range]
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thank you. But I'm not sure this works for 2 reasons:

Comment: 1. Testing it in the VBA module immediate window returns 0 when the DOB is less then a year (due to Int rounding down). This isn't what I was after. I want it to still return the data as a portion of the year if they are under 1 years old. Will it still work if I change all the Dim intAge and intYears to load in as doubles?
2. When I try to run this within my query it gives me an error either that it is too long/complex to run or that a particular select command is not valid.

Comment: 1. If you don't want to count years, count months, but an age in years below 1 is 0 (zero), so set 0 in `[Youngest Age in Range]` if babies should be included. 2. Specifying data type of the parameters may help. See expanded answer, please.

Comment: I adapted your function to give me the desired output when the age is less then 1, but it still won't work as part of the query. Even after I added the parameters command as you suggested. I've updated the question to contain the whole query, in case there are additional parts that are causing issues.

Comment: You may have to also add the remaining parameters (from the form) to the `Parameters` section.

Comment: I set them all to Short, but it still returns the same error: SELECT [Child Details1].Gender FROM [Child Details1]; is not a valid name...

Comment: That error indicates a missing or misspelled field or table name.

Comment: Hi Gustav, I tried to find any indication of missing or misspelled fields or table names but I couldn't find any. Is there any other reason this error might occur?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

To get the age in days (and then divide by 365.25 to get age as a fractional year) use

```
DateDiff("d",[DOB],Date())
```

not

```
DateDiff("y",[DOB],Date())
```